# How to retrieve title of YouTube video via URL

Tags: java, url, youtube-api

I have used this tutorial on the Java Youtube API to get the URL and thumbnail URLs for videos in a youtube search:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-youtube-java-api.html

What I now need to do is take the URL of the search results and retrieve the title of the video but I am not sure how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
videoEntry.getTitle().getPlainText();
```